# Beginner SQL - sum with JOIN possibly

Tags: php, sql

I am relatively new to SQL and have only dealt with very basic statements before.

Table A
 - id
 - clubid

Table B

- id
- applicationid* (foreign key)id above ^
- n
- p
- k
- mg
- area

What I am trying to do is as follows,

```
    SELECT * from applications WHERE clubid = $id
```

Then with the result of this I need to run a query along the lines of,

```
    SELECT Sum(n), Sum(p), Sum(k), Sum(mg) from productsapplied where area = $area
```

I know this second statement is wrong because it would be sum'ing each row which isnt possible so I am trying to find a way to link the two queries together. As I said I am a beginner with this, I have looked up on Sum as well as inner joins but can't get my head around it.

If more details are needed, let me know! Many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT Sum(productsapplied.n), Sum(productsapplied.p), Sum(productsapplied.k), Sum(productsapplied.mg)
 FROM productsapplied
 JOIN applications 
 ON productsapplied.applicationid = applications.id 
 WHERE productsapplied.area = $area
 AND applications.clubid = $id
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much, it looks very much like what I was after, I try to implement this and see if it works, what type of join is this may I ask ? So I can read into it more.

Comment: If you don't specify a JOIN it defaults to INNER JOIN if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: yes default is INNER JOIN and if you want OUTER JOIN you need to call it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a GROUP BY clause to your query.

```
SELECT applications.id, applications.clubid, sum(products.n), sum(products.p) 
FROM applications 
JOIN productsapplied AS products
ON productsapplied.applicationid = application.id
GROUP BY application.id
WHERE clubid = $id AND products.area = $area;
```

Note that you will need to set GROUP BY appropriately. I am assuming that we are summing for each applicationid. I also didn't do every detail of each column as I assume you can figure that out on your own.

Comment: Hi thanks, I think each applicationid corresponds to just one row, so I don't know if the group by is needed ?

Comment: I wasn't sure if application.clubid was one to one with application.id. As well as other assumptions.

Comment: very sorry, i should have made this clear, clubid is one to many with applications. 
applications is one to one with productsapplied

Comment: GROUP BY tells the query what it is that you are summing. Oh and to help clarify JOIN(s) INNER says we want where both match (ON) but none of anything else, LEFT/RIGHT give all rows from the left or right table respectively and only those rows that match (ON). FULL gives all row and join together those that match(ON).

Comment: Ok im confused. Did you just hear that correct. Your Foreign Key is a One to One relationship between the two tables. So for each record in table A you have a record in table B but no more one. If that is correct you should merge these two tables unless your doing it for very good reason.

Comment: well at the moment it is a one to one, as the part that will make it a one to many on my website isnt working (javascript) to make another form input. So eventually it will be one to many, but thanks for pointing that out